Looking for a Manga about Kaguya and transference of consciousness
I think I'm spending so much time in SE but anyway, here we go. I'm looking for a fantasy manga with some elements of sci-fi. I barely remember the actual plot of the story but I do recall the mc (a guy) fell in love with Kaguya. But Kaguya actually came down using a sort of UFO-esque ship (and is dead, I think). It has a harem genre with other girls trying to get the guy's attention(?). Apparently, these girls and some (if not most) of the women in this place transfer their consciousness to a baby as a form of "rebirth". I distinctly remember a woman wearing a kimono transferring her consciousness to a baby and she actually spoke as a baby and remarked that it's hard speaking because the baby has yet to fully develop. About the mc, I think he's obsessed with Kaguya and tries to create or fix the ship she came in. I'm not sure about how it went through. Also, he met this girl that has a scar from a heart surgery who is also part of the women in that village (or shrine).
Additional notes:

The story is set in the present or at least "modern" where cellphones and tvs currently exist already because from what I can remember, the MC is wearing modern clothes.
The MC also have flashbacks from a past life when he was living with Kaguya at that time (that past era is probably where the original Kaguya story is set in)
Women in this manga also wears modern clothes while some wears kimono.


By Kaguya you mean a character named kaguya? Or the character named Kaguya Shinomiya or Kaguya-hime no Monogatari or kaguya otsutsuki ?

The mention of the UFO and the MC being obsessed with Kaguya does make this sound like a retelling of Tale of the Bamboo Cutter.

@someoneuseless I'm pretty sure she's the Kaguya-hime like from the tale, Kaguya-hime no Monogatari. But this Kaguya has a twist and I think from what I recall she technically died in the story.

@qazmlpok I think I will edit the question. The MC belongs in our modern era and the women where the MC lives with currently wears modern clothes from what I can remember.
